# Linux Centos6 VM How to download bigtop?

Tags: linux, hadoop, centos6, bigtop

I am new in this subject. I have been following directives in Hadoop for Dummies book. At step 2 while trying to install bigtop, got this error in below.
[image]

OS : windows 8
VM: Centos6

Comment: just solved it, it was because of the expired link , it was replaced with https://archive.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-0.7.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo

Comment: You may answer your question instead of commenting

Comment: @cricket_007 i have an another issue at the moment. When using the yum install command, it starts downloading well but speed keeps decrease and becomes zero before it is done then having pycurl error 22 "requested url returned error 403" trying other mirror... do you have any idea?

Comment: Well 403 is access denied or forbidden, so no, I don't have any ideas. I'm not good at networking issues

Comment: ok, ty for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved it, it was because of the expired link , it was replaced with
https://archive.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-0.7.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo